# How do I parse empty dictionary JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am parsing JSON using swift. I came to a dictionary which returns empty. How would I go about parsing this into a custom object?

** I am looking at `Image`**

```
},
        "name": "Al bake",
        "image": {},
        "website": "",
        "category": {
            "id": "d59d2b1c-ca37-4c76-bb93-1c0ba967ee84",
            "name": "Test Category",
            "slug": "test-category",
            "is_active": true
        },
```

Comment: Why you need to parse it ?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn how to do this =]

Comment: Your image key is just a empty dictionary.Are you asking how to parse json data?

Comment: Correct. How would I create a struct or class for it? Like a custom object?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value for `image`, which should be a dictionary (empty or containing keys & values), you need to know the type that contains it.

For instance, let's assume that the following code is contained in a dictionary:

```
"name": "Al bake",
"image": {},
"website": "",
"category": {
    "id": "d59d2b1c-ca37-4c76-bb93-1c0ba967ee84",
    "name": "Test Category",
    "slug": "test-category",
    "is_active": true
```

You would do something like this:

```
if let image = dictionary["image"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
    print(image.description)
} else {
    print("Image does not contain a value")
}
```

Comment: What is I wanted to set it to `null` ?

Comment: Are you looking to create a custom object from the entire JSON data structure, or do you just want to retrieve the value for the `image` key?

Comment: Create a custom object just for the image